# Heap_size in heap_sort

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, heapsort

I'm reading Cormen's "Introduction to Algorithms", and I'm trying to implement a heap-sort, and there's one thing I continually fail to understand: how do we calculate the `heap_size` for a given array?
My textbook says

> An array A that represents a heap is an object with two attributes:
>   A.length, which (as usual) gives the number of elements in the array,
>   and A.heap-size, which represents how many elements in the heap are
>   stored within array A. That is, although A[1 .. A.length] may contain
>   numbers, only the elements in A[1..A.heap-size],where 0 <= A.heap-size <=
>   A.length, are valid elements of the heap.

If I implement an array as `std::vector<T> Arr`, then its' size would be `Arr.size`, but what would its' heap_size be is currently beyond me.

Comment: Clearly, and already understand what it is, now I need a means to actually calculate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The heap size should be a separately stored variable, which you manage yourself.

Whenever you remove from or add to the heap, you should decrement or increment the value appropriately.

In C++, using a `vector`, you may actually be able to use the `size`, since the underlying representation is an array that's at least as big as the size of the vector, and it's guaranteed to stay the same size if you call `resize` with a smaller size. (So the underlying array will be the array size and the vector size will be the heap size).

Comment: So I can state something like `int heap_size (std::vector<T> Arr) {return Arr.size;}` and hope for the best?

Comment: @Chiffa As long as you resize the vector when you insert / remove, it will work. The separation between array size and heap size is actually just a (very significant) optimization that avoids freeing and reallocating memory after each insert / remove. Also, don't pass by value (it creates an unnecessary copy), pass by `const` reference instead - `int heap_size (const std::vector<T> &Arr)`.